# Can I use media Home Sharing with visionOS?

Tags: home-sharing, visionos

Using [Home Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/108958) I can browse my home movies on iOS and iPadOS in the *TV* app via Library, and on tvOS on the built-in *Computers* app.

But in visionOS I cannot find an equivalent. What's the "Apple way" to share media to a Vision Pro?